# Design Xaml grid with height = 100% and minimum row height size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, grid

Here's the problem. I have a grid with some data written in xaml:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObjectCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="Auto">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="27"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="75" MinHeight="30"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Name="LabelNumber" Content="{Binding ObjectID}" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource MyStyleLabel}" />
                    <control:FocusMeterControl x:Name="HorizontalFocusMeterControl" Value="{Binding ObjectProperty}" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="1" />

                    <Button Name="RemoveObject" Content="-" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Tag="{Binding Point}" Style="{StaticResource MyStyleButton}" />

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

As you can see I'm creating a new grid for each member in my "MyObjectCollection". Ideally I think I should just create one row instead since this would make my next problem - the real problem easier.

However, I have not found any good way to do this in xaml if even possible. Is this possible without populating the collection manually from c# and setting a row-property in my objects manually in order to do something like this

```
<Label Name="LabelNumber" Grid.Row="{Binding ManuallyCalculatedRowID}" ... />
```

My primary problem is that I would like the grid/rows to all be equally high and if possible fill out the parent window. If the parent window is way too large MaxHeight should apply and I would just like some empty space below.

The parent control is a Windows Form ElementHost if that makes any difference.

Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Answer (score 0):

To make all rows of equal hight we can use [ItemsPanelTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemspaneltemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set it to [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.UniformGrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will take care of equal sizing problem:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObjectCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="Auto">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="27"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Name="LabelNumber" Content="{Binding ObjectID}" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource MyStyleLabel}" />
                <control:FocusMeterControl x:Name="HorizontalFocusMeterControl" Value="{Binding ObjectProperty}" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="1" />

                <Button Name="RemoveObject" Content="-" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Tag="{Binding Point}" Style="{StaticResource MyStyleButton}" />

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note that I removed row definition in `ItemTemplate` to lift vertical size restrictions for items. Not sure if that answers your question but that can be good starting point on the road to solution.